# ajax onkeyup event 501 from rapid input

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest, onkeyup

On the Javascript side of things I registered an event listener to a text `<input>` for the `onkeyup` event.

Each time the event is triggered, a function is invoked that creates an `xmlhttprequest` object that passes the input's `value` as an url encoded `POST` variable to the request.

The request page is an `aspx` script which accepts the post variable, does some processing on it, and adds the processed input as a parameter to a MS SQL query.  The result set produced from executing the query is placed into a `dataset` which is converted to XML and then transformed via an XSLT into XHTML that is then inserted into the page that made the ajax call via the `innerHTML` injection method.

If you've followed me so far, the result is a full-text search on an MS SQL DB that produces results for each key release.  It is also worth mentioning that I am using MS SQL 2005 and IIS6.0.

The system seems to work great, except for one test-case.  That is when someone just pounds input as fast as they possibly can the server eventually returns `501 internal server errors` for each request.  After a few minutes, it seems to "fix" itself and operate normally again.  I was unable to gleam any useful information from IIS about these internal errors.

Now this is mere speculation, but my first assumptions were that either there were too many open simultaneous requests that had not yet finished, or that there were too many requests being made in a short period.

My initial thought was to create a *queue* of these `xmlhttprequests` and only open one at a time.

However, rather than the queue I tried this:

Each `onkeyup`:

1. Call `abort` on the last `xmlhttprequest` that was generated by `onkeyup`
2. Create a new `xmlhttprequest` for this `onkeyup`

This procedure appears to eliminate the problem.

What I was unable to do was determine the root cause of this issue: is it a server limitation? or is it a browser limitation?  Is there some other way to solve this problem without needing this abort procedure?

I can post code if necessary, but the code is very lengthy and many technologies are at use in this project so I'm not sure if it would really help anyone answer this question.

Comment: making ajax calls onkeyup is probably not a good idea. it is most likely a browser limitation, i remember reading something that most browsers will only allow 7 or 8 simultaneous asynch operations.

Comment: browser will not spew 501 error. It is ultimately a server limitation, because the server controls the http response code.

Comment: I don't think it's that far-fetched, though.  For example, take a very common web-site many are familiar with: www.google.com; by no means is my project anywhere near the scope of google's but if you notice in your console each keypress in the search input makes a GET request.  Presumably for their auto-complete feature.

Comment: Yes, your server is likely overloading. You could set a timeout on keyup, or unbind your handler at each keyup and then rebind it on success.

Comment: I was investigating IIS6.0 limitations, I can't seem to find the specs.  I mean even if I send out 30 requests supposedly IIS can handle thousands of simultaneous connections so I don't think it should be overloaded?  Unless it's some security thing.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at debouncing.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/debounce-your-javascript-functions